# Accessing HttpContext in ASP.NET Core 2.2 Class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, httpcontext

I need to access the `HttpContext.Current` in a class library in ASP.NET Core 2.2

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("SAMLart")
```

I'm attempting to port the code over and `HttpContext` doesn't even have `Current` in a main web project when I attempt to just try using a method in a HomeController.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm also facing this in a CLASS LIBRARY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Or you can also register as follows

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then in your class libray

```
public class Test 
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public Test(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Path..
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I do have a class library - so in a class library there is NO startup... thoughts?